# Configure Apache httpd to ignore/block a specific HTTP method?

Tags: apache-2.2, http-method

Is it possible to configure Apache httpd to ignore/block a specific HTTP method? If so, how?

I've tried adding the following but it didn't make any difference, non-listed methods still get through:

```
<LimitExcept GET HEAD PUT POST DELETE OPTIONS>
</LimitExcept>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`<Limit>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limit) or [`<LimitExcept>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitexcept) section.

Comment: Do you know what to put inside it to block it? Deny from all doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limit